# Multiple approval process in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I have a form which is submitted by a student and needs approval by different people based on the type of form. How can I achieve this in Laravel?
Ex. Student 1 submits Form type 1 which requires approval of Instructor and advisor in that order. The advisor would get notification to approve only when instructor approves it.

I have tried creating columns for each type of approver around(5) and check if the approver has approved and set the field. The issue with this approach is that the table has many columns.

I created a table with approvers and the priority for the approver for the specific form and based on that send the notification.

I know there should be a better way to achieve this.

```php
$firstApprover = $form->approvallist->where('priority', '1')->first();
```

** Here approvallist is a relationship to a ApprovalList table which contains the list of people who approve this particular form type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can maintain a many-to-many relation. The tables would be, students, form_types and the pivot table could be form_type_student. In the pivot table, you will store the type of the form, student id and additionally two fields. One is approver_id (the person who approves) and is_approved(boolean) whether it is approved or not.

And then you can check if the form type submitted by the student was approved or not and if approved who approved it

Answer (score 1):

There are "approval" components ready to use for Laravel. For example [first](https://github.com/stephenlake/laravel-approval) or [second](https://github.com/mtvs/eloquent-approval). Just google Laravel approval and pick whichever suits your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume that you are using the Application and Reviewer tables. I suggest linking them with many to many relation. Pivot table can have custom fields "approved" (0 by default) and "priority" in the pivot table. Set the Application's approved flag only when the last confirmation is received.

See https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: This sounds like a good approach. Thanks so much for the response. Can you elaborate on how I can define priority of the approvers?